# How can i find all the files via read filename from a txt file use shell

Tags: shell

I want to find out all the files via given filename, and then copy to another dir
my code:

```
while IFS= read -r file; do
  echo $file
  find /data/upload -name $file -exec cp {} ~/myimgs \;
done < "file_name.txt"
```

but it not working, someone can help me? Thanks

Comment: What happens exactly with your script ? The first line with IFS= is a bit strange.

Comment: I would suggest putting $file in quotes for the find command.

Comment: I tried your script it works for me. I suggest to add the full path for file_name.txt. You might be not on the directory of file_name.txt when you ran the script.